# Retrieve JSON data from get request python

Tags: python, json, api, flask, request

I am trying to recieve data in JSON format, documentation at - https://chargepoints.dft.gov.uk/api/help API.

However when I run this

```
response = requests.get('http://chargepoints.dft.gov.uk/api/retrieve/registry/postcode/EC3A+7BR/limit/10/type/format/json/')
print(response)
```

it returns <Response [200]>. How can I get this data in JSON format?

*EDIT when I use response.json I get `<bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>` and when I use response.json() I get `JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I use `response.json()` I get `JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value)`

This basically means that the response content is not a valid json.

How to diagnose stuff like that?

In Python, you can check unformatted `response.content` (property, so no parentheses) and analyse what you see... but since it's a simple GET without any auth or anything, just paste the url in your browser.

This is what you get:

```
<p:ChargeDevices xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.pod-point.com/cxns/NCR/1 National_Chargepoint_Registry.xsd ">
<Scheme>
<SchemeCode>NA</SchemeCode>
<SchemeData>
<OrganisationName>NA</OrganisationName>
<Website>NA</Website>
<TelephoneNo>NA</TelephoneNo>
</SchemeData>
...
```

This is XML, not JSON. You may wonder why you didn't get JSON, while you wrote your `/format/json/` in the url...

Looking at the [API documentation](http://chargepoints.dft.gov.uk/api/help) and testing it in the browser, I finally realised that /type/ part in your url doesn't have a pair. You got it from one json example and /type was the endpoint name there.

Remove the `/type` part and it works:

```
response = requests.get('http://chargepoints.dft.gov.uk/api/retrieve/registry/postcode/EC3A+7BR/limit/10/format/json/')
print(response.json())
```

The API is badly written - using /option/value format makes this thing hard to spot (in RESTful API, it should be option=value&option2=value2)... Still not the worst api I've seen, but it's pretty bad design that it didn't return any error information for /type/format/json part - either that it doesn't know "type" option or that "json" "option" has no value provided...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and concise response :) I was confused by the documentation at first but this clears everything up.

Comment: I have been recieving data sucessfully using the .json() method, however I am now getting a new error whilst using the same code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66890152/json-decoding-error-with-url-that-displays-data-in-the-browser - whilst the URL displays JSON data in the browser. I am at a loss..

Answer (score 0):

You can get the response data by calling `response.json()`

Comment: *`.json()` - it's a method, not a property like `.content` :)

Comment: When I do this I get  - <bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>

Comment: @OfirGottesman then you're calling it on something else, not `Response` object. `response.json` is a method and was in Python2-compatible versions. https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/ - just see the first example, at the top of the page...

Comment: @Stuey17 that comment proved my comment. :) But for your current problem: getting 200 but "expecting value" means API returns non-json data. I'll write an answer because it will get too long for the comment

Answer (score 0):

You can get the response data by getting `response.json` or you can get the raw text by `response.text`
then you can use json library to convert easily

```
import json
import requests

def get_json_from_url(url):
    content = get_url(url)
    js = json.loads(content)
    return js


def get_url(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    content = response.content.decode('utf8')
    return content

url='https://chargepoints.dft.gov.uk/api/help'
json_content=get_json_from_url(url)
```